# What's the best way to iterate over $data in Vue js with v-for?

Tags: vue.js

So I have this:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        firstName: {text: null, error: null},
        lastName: {text: null, error: null},
        email: {text: null, error: null},
        phone: {text: null, error: null},
        message: {text: null, error: null},
    },
…
```

One iterates over arrays like so:

```
…
    <li v-for="item in items">
…
```

But how do I do that without putting all my objects into an array? Basically, I want to access the top level data object. The following doesn't work:

```
…
    <li v-for="item in data">
…
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a computed function that renders an array and use it in your vue html:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    data: {
        firstName: {text: null, error: null},
        lastName: {text: null, error: null},
        email: {text: null, error: null},
        phone: {text: null, error: null},
        message: {text: null, error: null},
    },
    computed: {
        dataArr() {
            let arr = [this.firstName, this.lastName, this.email, this.phone, this.message]
            return arr
        }
}
…
```

On the html part, you can just call:

```
<li v-for="item in dataArr">
```

Computed variables update dinamically, so any change on data will be reflected in the computed array.

Hope it suits you well.